# How to reload part of the code in tkinter many times?

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

In the code below, a part of the main code is placed. I want this file, which is updated at different times, to be updated in tekinter, but the problem is that my UI is not updated until it is closed and opened.

```
style = ttk.Style(GLabel_820)
style.theme_use('clam')
style.configure("mystyle.Treeview", highlightthickness=0,bd=0,font=('Far_Nazanin', 11))
style.configure("mystyle.Treeview.Heading", font=('Far_Nazanin', 15)) 
style.layout("mystyle.Treeview", [('mystyle.Treeview.treearea', {'sticky': 'nswe'})])

tree = ttk.Treeview(GLabel_820)
tedadtardod=0      
filename = 'output/pelak1.xlsx'
filename = r"{}".format(filename)
df = pd.read_excel(filename,engine='openpyxl')
tedadkhat=len(df)
tree["column"] = list(df.columns)
tree["show"] = "headings"

for col in tree["column"]:
    tree.heading(col, text=col)
    df_rows = df.to_numpy().tolist()
    for row in df_rows:
        tedadtardod=tedadtardod+1
        if tedadtardod>tedadkhat-10:
            tree.insert("",0,values=row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, with my research I managed to solve my problem, so I'm posting the result here for others to use

```
def reload(self):
    while True :
        try :
            gf = pd.read_excel('output/pelak1.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')
            break
        except EOFError as e:
            time.sleep(1)
    NewPelakLength=len(gf)
    global LastPelakLength
    global toc
    tic = time.perf_counter()
    elap=tic-toc
    if NewPelakLength != LastPelakLength:# or elap>10
        toc = time.perf_counter()
        LastPelakLength=len(gf)
        self.pelak_list()
    self.after(6000, self.reload)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing that part of the code in a loop.
You can use a while loop or a for loop.

Comment: Many windows, buttons, and photos are displayed in the UI with the tekinter, besides these, there are options that are set interactively with the user, so it is not possible to use the loop.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).